# Trigger calculation, on insert of one table effect on other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

IDEA:

Having a table of **item**, **user**, **assign** now if I assign one item to user which the record will be save on table of **assign**,

```
table_item:
ID------INT
NAME----TEXT
COUNT---INT

table_user:
ID-------INT
NAME-----TEXT

table_assing:
ID------INT
USER----INT (user id)
ITEM----INT (item_id)
COUNT---INT (this is for subtractions from the column of COUNT table of item)
```

Here I want to set trigger on inserting to table (**table_assing**) the value of column **COUNT** should subtract from column of **COUNT** table of **table_item**

This is possible on PHP that I can set to query on once action but it will take lots of code if it's possible on MySQL that will be much better and fast and effective with accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple trigger after insert on table table_assign

```
UPDATE table_item
     SET table_item.count = (table_item.count - NEW.table_assign.count)
   WHERE table_item.id = table_assign.item
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

`DELIMITER $$
USE database_name$$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON table_asign FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_item SET count=count+NEW.count WHERE id=NEW.id;
END;$$`

The 'NEW.id' refers to the new row in the table 'table_asign'